Switch and case in C++ not working how expected
I'm using a switch and it seems to be giving me the last case no matter what the variable is set to. I expect it to be switching based on actually equals.
I have got the program to output each thing added to the list as I add it, to check if it was right. I was expecting C1-13 then D1-13 then A1-13 then S1-13, but it does S1-13 each time instead.
Here is my code:
vector<string> fullDeck;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    string letter;
    cout << i << endl;
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        letter = 'C';//club
    case 2:
        letter = 'D';//diamond
    case 3:
        letter = 'A';//ace
    case 4:
        letter = 'S';//spade
    }
    cout << letter << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << j;
        string num;
        ss >> num;
        fullDeck.push_back(letter + num);
        cout << fullDeck.back() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

And here is the output:
 

Missing break;, Increase the warning level of your compiler.

For your next question: don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

This would be a good time to learn how to step through your code in a debugger.  If you had done that, there would be no mystery.

Unlike some other programming languages, switch statements in C++ (like C) "fall through" cases by default (so, in your code, execution from case 1 continues to case 2, then case 3 ..... ) .  To prevent that behaviour, place a break; statement at the end of the code for each case (unless, of course, you WANT the default behaviour).    This, incidentally, is described in detail in most introductory texts in C or C++.
